# Parsing data from local JSON file (SWIFT)

Tags: json, swift, xcode, dictionary, parsing

I am developing an app for Aphasia patients that requires them to choose an appropriate answer for a particular question. For instance, if the question is 'acquire' the corresponding answer they should select is 'company'. Currently I have a JSON file that has the questions and answers stored which I am trying to parse the data to get specific information out of it which brings me to my first question: After writing the code below, I keep getting and error when I requested it to print, questions and answers.

[image]

This is the screenshot of the JSON file.
[image]

My next question would be after parsing I would like to separate the data into different dictionaries like such :

```
questions = ["include","acquire"]
answers = [["sale","border","water foxtail","condition"],["company", "capacity", "debt","note"]]
```

The questions dictionary is supposed to be filled with the values from key 'QN' from my JSON file and the answers are the value from the keys'ANS','PHO','RAN'. I know it is a bit confusing but I would like to keep both the keys and values for my answers dictionary. Sorry for the really long question and thank you for any help!

Comment: Print the actual error instead of a hard coded string, `print(error)` and include your json as text and not an image

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, would appreciate the upvote!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all lets look into you decoding flow step by step.

#### Decoding

1. If you are executing this code directly in your app target, and not in some separate library, for the sake of simplicity you can use `Bundle.main` to access the path of the json file

```swift
guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "questions", ofType: "json") else {
    return
}
```

2. To decode the json we want the data to pass it to the decoder, and we can do it without having it converted to string so lets initialise `Data` directly from url.

```swift
let data = try Data(contentsOf: path)
```

3. Since we are decoding multiple `QnAns` objects, the type passed to the decoder needs to be `Array` of `QnAns` so we write it like that:

```swift
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([QsAns].self, from: data)
```

> both `[QsAns]` and `Array<QsAns>` mean the same

4. There are many errors that can occur during this flow and `do-catch` statements make it easy to debug by passing us the exact error that was thrown at us, so lets take advantage of that and print it in the `catch` closure like so:

```swift
catch { print(error) }
```

#### Final Flow

With all that in mind we land with a pretty elegant code that is also not very long and reads nicely:

```swift
guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "questions", ofType: "json") else {
    return
}
do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: path)
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([QsAns].self, from: data)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

#### Cool! Is that all?

Unfortunately your json does not looks like its valid for decoder to read and be able to figure out its contents. To make it work we need to embed the objects into the array.
So instead of:

```json
{ ... }, 
{ ... }
```

We need

```json
[
    { ... }, 
    { ... }
]
```

#### Ooof!

That should be pretty much it. Let me know how it goes, I will be happy to update the answer if something is not clear of there are still some issues. Good luck!

#### Bonus Question!

We can easily convert these two arrays into the dictionary by using `zip` function

```swift
// type of dict will be [String: [String]]
let dict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(questions, answers))
```

Comment: hi, thank you so much for your reply! Really appreciate it, only thing is I run into an error when I try and write my print statements. I cannot attach a screenshot here so I will update my question with my problem above!

Comment: you will need to add these print statements into the try clause

Comment: qaAns is only visible there